# WiFi not working - 15.04 - Broadcom BCM4313 [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.04, broadcom

I will first start by describing my problem: I have a 2 WiFis that I want to use on Ubuntu, they first worked and then after a few days they stopped stopped working. I tried reinstalling the machine, with no luck. I swapped the modem with another one of the same model and after that it again worked but only for a few days until now, when it has again stopped working.

I tried searching for my answer and found there could be a driver problem.
My WiFi Card is: Broadcom BCM4314 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

I have gone through the thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2232939 
But the problem there was, like the #7 said, it does not work with the 'b43' driver. But I could not find the "brcmsmac" driver either. I tried installing 'wl', 'wl/brcm80211' and 'bcmwl-kernel-source' (reinstall) none of them helped me see my WiFi's SSID in the list of available networks. Though, I am not sure that the method I followed, i.e. The command I typed were 100% correct. So I could try again, the commands you want me to, to install the same drivers again.
Also looked at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx, but could not find any driver as such for "4727"

And I started with, and was basically trying to follow the steps given at https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/326313 , it originally asks me to install the same driver that WAS there by default. And even if I redo it, it does not work. So I tried variations of the method given there, with the foresaid drivers to try and replace them.

I can let you know the outputs of any command you tell me, and I would like to mention that I am new to Ubuntu.